# Get stripe webhook raw body with next js 13 app dir

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, next.js13

I'm trying to set up webhooks for stripe but I can't get the raw body of the request which I apparently need.
Code:

```
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export async function POST(request: any) {

console.log("BODY:", request.body) // Attached image
  try {
    const rawBody = await buffer(request); // error: invalid body
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  console.log("event received");
  return NextResponse.json({ status: 200 });
}
```

Apparently I need to set the bodyParser to false and then pass the request to the buffer function, but like this I get a "content-type is undefined" error, when I set it to true, I get a "invalid body" error

I've attached an image of what the request.body looks like, I don't know if it's supposed to look like that, so maybe that's the issue?

Comment: It looks like that is under discussion in this GH issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13405.  Several posters have work arounds they have developed.  See if any of these address your issue.